# Programmatically resize a view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4, swtbot

I'm testing an *non-e4* RCP application using SWTBot and I need to change the size of my view. (Move the sash-bar)

I unsuccessfully tried

- Resize my view using SWTBot (no such api)
- Resize my view using Eclipse 3 API (no supported)
- Resize my view using underlying e4 model (resizing not working)

e4 model seams to be promising, but I'm missing something, so it doesn't work.

I can

- Get MPart of my view: `view = ePartService.findPart(ID)`
- Get MTrimmedWindow: `window = (view as EObject).eContainer as MTrimmedWindow`

I can't

- locale correct MPartSashContainer
- move sash-bar with `setContainerData()`

I would like to know

- How can I move from MPart to its direct parent (e.g. MPartStack)
- Why common EObject methods like eContainer() are not present on M... objects?

Comment: `MPart` (and all other `MUIElement` objects) has a `getParent()` method which give you the immediate parent.

Comment: Unfortunately it returns null for my "view" MPart :(

Comment: Then it hasn't been added to a container yet. This **always** returns a parent for parts that are being shown.

Comment: @greg-449 I do `page.showView(ID,...)`, then wait for 5 seconds, then `ePartService.findPart(ID).getParent()` is still `null`. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what happens with part ids in 3.x compatibility mode. I am not sure that the id used by `IWorkbenchPage.showPage` is the same id as the application model MPart id.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a solution myself.

The thing is, that the view is not a part of the e4 UI-Tree. `view.eContainer` is directly the `MWindow`. To be placed at the right spot the view is connected to the `MPlaceholder`, that is a part of the e4 UI-Tree and has `getParent() != null`.

In order to resize a view the steps are:

- Show view
- Find `MPlaceholder` of the view
- Find `MPartStack` and `MPartSashContainer´ object
- Set `containerData`
- Redraw widget (yes, auto-update seam not to work in this case)

Example:

```
EModelService modelService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(EModelService.class);
EPartService  partService  = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(EPartService.class);

// Show view
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
page.showView(MyView.ID, null, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE);

MPart view = partService.findPart(MyView.ID);
// view.getParent() => null, because 'view' is not a part of the e4 UI-model!
// It is connected to the Model using MPlaceholder

// Let's find the placeholder
MWindow window = (MWindow)(((EObject)eView).eContainer);
MPlaceholder placeholder = modelService.findPlaceholderFor(window, view);

MUIElement element = placeholder;
MPartStack partStack = null;
while (element != null) {
    // This may not suite your configuration of views/stacks/sashes
    if (element instanceof MPartStack && ((Object)element.parent) instanceof MPartSashContainer) {
            partStack = (MPartStack)element;
            break;
        }
        element = element.parent;
    }
}
if (partStack == null) { /* handle error */ }

// Now let's change the width weights
for (MUIElement element : partStack.getParent().getChildren()) {
    if (element == partStack) {
        element.setContainerData("50"); // Width for my view
    } else {
        element.setContainerData("25"); // Widths for other views & editors
    }
}

// Surprisingly I had to redraw tho UI manually
// There is for sure a better way to do it. Here is my (quick & very dirty):
partStack.toBeRendered = false
partStack.toBeRendered = true
```