# How to set height of Stand alone view in a view in RCP application with different resolutions?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a RCP application with a stand alone view on the top. I have to set certain height for that view. To set it, i'm using

```
 Monitor monitor = Display.getCurrent().getMonitors()[0];
 Rectangle rect = monitor.getBounds();

 if (rect.width >= 1900 && rect.height >= 1000) {
          layout.addStandaloneView(MyView.VIEW_ID, false, IPageLayout.TOP, 
          0.130f, editorArea);
 }
 else if (rect.width >= 1200 && rect.height >= 900) {
          layout.addStandaloneView(MyView.VIEW_ID, false, IPageLayout.TOP, 
          0.135f, editorArea);
 }
```

This doesn't seems to work when I connect my laptop to an extended monitor or change the default resolution and text size of my extended monitor.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I assume this is in the perspective factory - this is only run when the perspective is first created or when it is reset.

Comment: Yes. It will execute while opening perspective

Comment: Only the very first time the perspective is used. The settings are cached after that and this code is not used when the perspective is used again.

Comment: Then I cannot change the height dynamically?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any way to adjust a perspective layout dynamically.

Comment: Checkout https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=51580 for help

Answer (score 1):

The "perspective layout" can be modified via E4 API as well as over E4 Workbench elements.
Please refer to this post [Programmatically resize a view in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202032/programmatically-resize-a-view-in-eclipse/47347113#47347113) for details.